# Android 4.0.4 - Wifi WPA-PSK hex password too long

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, password

I am currently trying to connect to a Wifi (WPA-PSK TKIP with 64-bit hex password). However my device - LG Optimus L9 with Android 4.0.4 - only allows to type in 63 characters.

It seems that it only support "passphrase" password which is supposed to be 8-63 characters long but not "hex" password..

Did anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Why hex password? Why not a usual combinations of letters/numbers?

Comment: Well that would be the "passphrase" I meantioned. I tried that.. I deleted the last character and it worked perfectly. However I have lots of devices using this network and I dont want to change the password for all of them just because of this.

Comment: 64bit hex password, so 64bits is 8 bytes, so the password length is in fact of 8, composed of letters/number? Clarify?

Comment: @t0mm13b: it's probably a 64 hex-char string what was meant (4bit per char, i.e. 4x64bit or 256bit binary key data). Also see here, it should be fixed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2009

Comment: @ce4 cheers for that tidbit of info - apparently post #7 on that linky is having some trouble too? I do recall issues with WPA supplicant when porting ICS... maybe a replacement binary is available?

Comment: it's >3.5 years since the bug was closed and 2 people complained. That's too few to be relevant. I'd say: Either it's case-sensitive (must be all lowercase) or someone mistyped it by accident (and a non hex char slipped in).

Comment: @t0mm13b Yes it is a 64 hex-char string.

Comment: @ce4 Thank you for the link. I (just to be sure) checked the password and it really contains hex characters only. I copy and paste the password in my android device so I am sure there's no typo.

Answer (score 1):

My experience: One friend's network uses WPA with a 64character hex-key and I haven't had any problem connecting to it since Android 2.3 Gingerbread.

I also had a look at the wifi config at `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` which holds all the wifi credentials. The one entry from above is configured just as every other with the exception that it has a 64 character hex key. I, of course censored both keys and SSIDs, fyi.

Here's a sample:

```
network={
        ssid="normal_psk_key_network"
        psk="secretpassphrase"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=1
}

network={
        ssid="64hexchar_network"
        psk=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        priority=2
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the file on a PC or on the phone? In other words - how do I access this "/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf" file? .. and after that, do you think it would be possible to edit it, just to add the last character of my password?

Comment: I have a rooted phone and used USB debugging (ADB) to view it on the command line. It's probably possible to add it, at least if you're already root it's little effort to try it. Not sure which editor does a good job (I prefer non-graphical commandline tools). Maybe try OI file explorer or ghost commander (they support root mode and include an editor). What may also work: Google offers wifi passphrase sync iirc. you could set up your network from another phone.